# Merge FAST two DataFrames based on specific conditions, row by row

Tags: python, pandas, merge, apply

I have been struggling with my case for the past 10 days and I can't find a **fast and efficient** solution.

Here is the case. I have one DF containing web traffic data of a human resources website.
Every row of this Dataframe refers to an application (aka : someone reached the website via a specific web source, and apply to a specific job offer at a specific time).
Here is an example :

```
import pandas as pd
web_data = {'source':  ['Google', 'Facebook','Email'],
        'job_id': ['123456', '654321','010101'],
        'd_date_hour_event' : ['2019-11-01 00:09:59','2019-11-01 00:10:41','2019-11-01 00:19:20'],
        }
web_data = pd.DataFrame(web_data)
```

On the second DataFrame, I have an extract of a Human Resources internal tool where we gather all the received appplications with some complementary data. Here is an example :

```
hr_data ={'candidate_id':  ['ago23ak', 'bli78gro','123tru456'],
        'job_id': ['675848', '343434','010101'],
        'date_time_submission' : ['2019-11-10 00:24:59','2019-11-09 12:10:41','2019-11-01 00:19:22'],
         'job_label':['HR internship','Data Science Supervisor','Project Manager']
        }

hr_data = pd.DataFrame(hr_data)
```

Here are the difficulties I am facing :

- There is not a unique key I can use to merge those two tables. I have to use the "Job_id" (which is unique to every job) combined with the time when the application occured via the columns "d_date_hour_event" (on web_data DF) and "date_time_submission"  (on hr_data DF).
- For the same application, the time registered on the 2 tables might not be the same (difference of few seconds)
- Some of web_data values might not be present in hr_data

In the end, I would like to get one DataFrame that looks like this :

[result_dataframe.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYVl2.png)

Actually, I already coded the function to realize this merge. It looks like this :

```
for i, row in web_data.iterrows() :
    #we stock the needed value for hr_data research
    date = row.d_date_hour_event
    job = row.job_id
    
    #we compute the time period
    inf = date - timedelta(seconds=10)
    sup = date + timedelta(seconds=10)
    
    #we check if there a matching row in hr_data
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame()
    temp_df = hr_data[(hr_data.job_id == job) & \
                         (hr_data.date_time_submission >= inf) & (hr_data.date_time_submission <= sup)].tail(1)
    
    #if there is a matching row, we merge them and update web_data table
    if not temp_df.empty:
        row = row.to_frame().transpose()
        
        join = pd.merge(row, temp_df, how='inner', on='job_id',left_index=False, right_index=True)
        
        web_data.update(join)
```

But, because my Web_data is over 250K rows and my HR_data is over 140k rows, it takes hours ! (estimation of 35hours running script...).

I am sure that the iterrows is not optimal and that this code can be optimized. I tried to use a custom function with **.apply(lambda x: ...)** but without success.

Any help would be more than welcome !

Please let me know if you need more explanations.

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this in a few steps:

**1.** Convert the datetime columns in both dataframes to pd.datetime format.

```
web_data = web_data.assign(d_date_hour_event= lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['d_date_hour_event']))
hr_data = hr_data.assign(date_time_submission=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['date_time_submission']))
```

**2.** Rename the `job_id` of the `hr_data` dataframe so it will not provide any errors when merging.

```
hr_data = hr_data.rename(columns={"job_id": "job_id_hr"})
```

**3.** Make `numpy` arrays from the columns containing `timestamps` and `job_ids` in both dataframes and check for rows in which the timestamp in the `web_data` dataframe is within 10 seconds of the `timestamp` in the `hr_data` dataframe and have the same `job_id` using `numpy` broadcasting.

```
web_data_dates = web_data['d_date_hour_event'].values
hr_data_dates = hr_data['date_time_submission'].values
web_data_job_ids = web_data['job_id'].values
hr_data_job_ids = hr_data['job_id_hr'].values

i, j = np.where(
    (hr_data_dates[:, None] <= (web_data_dates+pd.Timedelta(10, 'S'))) & 
    (hr_data_dates[:, None] >= (web_data_dates-pd.Timedelta(10, 'S'))) & 
    (hr_data_job_ids[:, None] == web_data_job_ids)
)

overlapping_rows = pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([web_data.values[j], hr_data.values[i]]),
    columns=web_data.columns.append(hr_data.columns)
)
```

**4.** Assign new columns to the original `web_data` dataframe, so we can update these rows with all the information in case any rows overlap

```
web_data = web_data.assign(candidate_id=np.nan, job_id_hr=np.nan, date_time_submission=np.datetime64('NaT'), job_label=np.nan)
```

**Finally** just update `web_data` dataframe (or first create a copy if you don't want to overwrite the original datframe)

```
web_data.update(overlapping_rows)
```

Must be a lot faster than iterating over all rows

Comment: Many thanks Rik, just some questions before I try your code :

Comment: Sorry, double post : 

Many thanks Rik, just some questions before I try your code :
- Did you take into consideration the "double-key" to check for overlapping ? Because there might be a lot of applications that occur in a range of 10 seconds, If I don't check the match between job_id and job_id_hr, I might end with a lot of overlapped rows don't you think ? 

I'll try it anyway :)

Comment: No sorry, but easy to add. I will update the answer :).

Comment: Hey again Rik, unfortunately, it doesn't work. The reason why it doesn't, seems to be related to size of arrays. Becaues my web_data DF and hr_data DF are not the same size (250k rows vs 140k rows), the np.where doesn't want to work. 

I tried too with the examples I provided. It words perfectly fine when both of DFs are 3 rows lenght, but it doesn't work anymore when I add one more row in one of them.

And an error occured ==> DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.

Any wordaround ? :) 
Thanks

Comment: Also, I did not mention it (but it is implicit with the fact that both of DFs are not the same size), it is indeed possible that the application registered at the 1000th row (for example) of web_data DF could be matched up with the 23400th row of the hr_data DF....

I tried mixing position in the test example (switching the position of the 3rd row of web_data DF with the second row) and even with both DF having the same size (3 rows each) , because the 3rd row of web_data DF does not match the 3rd row of hr_data DF (ike it did previously), the np_where doesn't detect the match correctly . :(

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake when updating the answer for checking the match between `job_ids`. Should be `(hr_data_job_ids[:, None] == web_data_job_ids)` instead of `(hr_data_job_ids[:, None] == web_data_job_ids[:, None])`. Can you try again with the updated answer? Especially if it works for mixing up the test examples?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I am using (which is not working unless you make the changes I described in comments)

```
web_data = {'source':  ['Google', 'Facebook','Email'],
        'job_id': ['123456', '654321','010101'],
        'd_date_hour_event' : ['2019-11-01 00:09:59','2019-11-01 00:10:41','2019-11-01 00:19:20'],
        }
web_data = pd.DataFrame(web_data)

#placed '010101'  and '2019-11-01 00:19:22' in second position instead of third position like it used to be
#if you reswitch these values to 3rd position in respectively 'job_id' and 'date_time_submission' arrays, it should work
hr_data ={'candidate_id':  ['ago23ak', 'bli78gro','123tru456'],
        'job_id': ['675848', '010101','343434'],
        'date_time_submission' : ['2019-11-10 00:24:59','2019-11-01 00:19:22','2019-11-09 12:10:41'],
         'job_label':['HR internship','Data Science Supervisor','Project Manager']
        }

hr_data = pd.DataFrame(hr_data)

hr_data = hr_data.rename(columns={"job_id": "job_id_hr"})

web_data = web_data.assign(d_date_hour_event= lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['d_date_hour_event']))
hr_data = hr_data.assign(date_time_submission=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['date_time_submission']))

web_data_dates = web_data['d_date_hour_event'].values
hr_data_dates = hr_data['date_time_submission'].values
web_data_job_ids = web_data['job_id'].values
hr_data_job_ids = hr_data['job_id_hr'].values

i, j = np.where(
    (hr_data_dates[:, None] <= (web_data_dates+pd.Timedelta(10, 'S'))) & 
    (hr_data_dates[:, None] >= (web_data_dates-pd.Timedelta(10, 'S'))) & 
    (hr_data_job_ids[:, None] == web_data_job_ids[:, None])
)

overlapping_rows = pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([web_data.values[j], hr_data.values[i]]),
    columns=web_data.columns.append(hr_data.columns)
)

overlapping_rows
```

Comment: As you can see, I already added [:, None] to web_data_job_ids. 
If you execute the script as it is written above, the "overlapping_rows" will be empty

Comment: Yes, you have to remove the `[:, None]` after `web_data_jobs_id` (see also my edited answer). Then the overlapping rows contain the right rows that overlap.